# remove all quote using regexp

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove all quotes from a string INCLUDE nested quotes.

it does not works for nested qoutes:

```
preg_replace("/\[quote(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/i","", $text);
```

this works for something like:

```
[quote=admin]Welcome to RegExr 0.3b, an intuitive tool for learning, writing, and testing Regular Expressions. Key features include: [/quote]
```

but not for:

```
[quote=admin]Welcome to RegExr 0.3b, [quote] an intuitive tool for learning, [/quote] writing, and testing Regular Expressions. Key features include: [/quote]
```

would like to remove all qoute blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake simply is the question mark in your expression.

Try `preg_replace("/\[quote(.*?)\](.*)\[\/quote\]/i","", $text);`

With your example posted in your edit:

```
$text = '[quote=admin]Welcome to RegExr 0.3b, [quote] an intuitive tool for learning, [/quote] writing, and testing Regular Expressions. Key features include: [/quote]';
$cleared = preg_replace("/\[quote(.*?)\](.*)\[\/quote\]/i","", $text);

var_dump($cleared);
// -> string(0) ""
```

Comment: no. this works for something like: "[quote=admin]Welcome to RegExr 0.3b, an intuitive tool for learning, writing, and testing Regular Expressions. Key features include: [/quote]" but not for: "[quote=admin]Welcome to RegExr 0.3b, [quote] an intuitive tool for learning, [/quote] writing, and testing Regular Expressions. Key features include: [/quote]"

Comment: I just want to remove all quote blocks with it's contents included nested one from a string. (first post updated with example)

Comment: And the result would be an empty string for your examples?

Comment: this is exactly what i get with the expression i posted

Comment: that not works if we have more than one block for exmaple: [quote=admin]Welcome to RegExr 0.3b, an intuitive tool for learning, writing, and testing Regular Expressions. Key features include: [/quote]
[quote]sdfsdf [quote]
*  ll over a match to see details & view group info below 
* built in regex your expression 
* online & desktop: regexr.com or download the desktop version for Mac, Windows, or Linux [/quote]
* save your expressions: My Saved expressions are saved locally 
* share and rate expressions: search Community expressions and share your own 
[/quote]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16728/discussion-between-thorsten-and-m3hdi)

Answer (score 1):

```
/\[quote.*?\](.*?)\[\/quote\]((\s)*(\[\/quote])*)*/gis
```

It's working but it's not complete.

Note that after [/quote] there is next [/quote] and next and ... and there isn't anything else. **This code remove all quotes that quoted** but not multiple quotes like:

```
[quote] ... [quote]...[/quote] ... [quote]...[/quote] ... [/quote]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not `str_replace('"', '', $string);`?

Edit: this is wrong answer. I've misread the question.

Comment: @egis not quotation marks. This "[quote]foo[/quote]". `str_replace()` is not right for this